# Get H2OFrame as object instead of getting reference to a location in H2O cluster

Tags: openshift, h2o

We have created and trained model using H2O libraries. Configured H2O in OpenShift container and deployed the trained model for getting realtime inference. It worked well when we have one container. We have to scale up to handle the increase in transaction volume. Encountered an issue with the statefull nature of the H2OFrame. Please see my sample code.

Step-1: Converts the JSON dictionary in to Pandas frame.
Step-2: Converts the Pandas frame in to H2O frame.
Step-3: Run the model with H2O frame as input.

Here step-2 is returning a handle to the data stored in the container. "H2OFrame is similar to pandas’ DataFrame, or R’s data.frame. One of the critical distinction is that the data is generally not held in memory, instead it is located on a (possibly remote) H2O cluster, and thus H2OFrame represents a mere handle to that data." So Step-3's request must go to the same container. If not it cannot find the H2O frame and throws error.

Step-1: convert JSON dictionary to data frame using Pandas dataFrame

```
 ToBeScored = pd.DataFrame([jsonDictionary])
```

Step-2: convert panda data frame to H2o frame

```
 ToBeScored_hex = h2o.H2OFrame(ToBeScored)
```

Step-3: run the model

```
 outPredections = rf_model.predict(ToBeScored_hex)
```

If the H2OFrame can be returned as an in memory object in step-2 then the statefull nature can be avoided. Is there any way?
Or, Can the H2O clustering be configured to store the H2OFrame such a way that it can be accessible from any OpenShift container in the cluster? 
 
Useful links 
 H2O’s Predict function accepts data only in H2OFrame format.
Predict function - http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.predict 
H2O frame data type - http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html

**Updated on 6/19/2019 continuation question to @ErinLeDell's clarification** 
We have upgraded to H2O 3.24 and used MOJO model. Removed step 2 and replaced step 3 with this function call.

```
import h2o as h 
result = h.mojo_predict_csv(input_csv_path="PredictionDataRow.csv",mojo_zip_path="rf_model.zip",
genmodel_jar_path="h2o-genmodel.jar", java_options='-Xmx512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m', verbose=True)
```

Internally it executed the below command which initialized a new JVM and started H2O local server for every call. H2O local server is initialized to find the path to java.

```
java = H2OLocalServer._find_java()   // Find java path then creates below command line

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -Xmx512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -cp h2o-genmodel.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PredictCsv --mojo C:\Users\admin\Documents\Code\python\rf_model.zip --input PredictionDataRow.csv --output C:\Users\admin\Documents\Code\python\prediction.csv --decimal
```

Question-1: Is there any way to use an existing JVM and not always spawn a new one for every transaction? 
Question-2: Is there a way to pass the java path to avoid the H2O local server initialization? Is H2OLocalServer required for anything other than finding java path? If it cannot be avoided then, Is it possible to initialize local server once and direct new requests to existing H2O local server instead of starting a new H2O local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use an H2O [MOJO](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#mojo-quick-start) model (instead of a [binary model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html) which needs to exist in H2O cluster memory to make predictions).  MOJO models can sit on disk and do not require a running H2O cluster.  Then you can skip Step 2 and use the [h2o.mojo_predict_pandas()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?#h2o.mojo_predict_pandas) function in Step 3.

Comment: We have tried MOJO option, but had difficulty in converting feature extraction logic from Python to Java. So we have kept the model as binary in H2O cluster and feature extraction logic in python. Any suggestions with the current deployment setup?

Comment: You can use MOJOs without using Java.  Keep all your same code in Python (including feature extraction logic), but save a MOJO model instead of a binary model and swap out the predict step with the `h2o.mojo_predict_pandas()` function.

Comment: Thank you Erin. This is very helpful.
Seems this feature is introduced in H2O 3.20.0.4 version.

Comment: @Mohan I'm not sure what you mean by "spawn a new JVM".  Do you mean "spawn a new H2O cluster"? One of the advantages of using MOJOs for scoring is that they don't require the H2O cluster to be running.

Comment: When the mojo_predict_pandas() method executed by H2O, we are seeing one JVM process per transaction in process monitor. It gets initiated per transaction and terminates after the transaction is complete. If you consider app server like JBOSS, it creates one JVM and all the requests go to the same running JVM. Agree that H2O cluster is not created but it is still initializing the H2OLocalServer to find JVM path. Any way to avoid H2OLocalServer initialization?